# How to close all the other related work items when a work item is closed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-workitem

Actually, I am writing MSFlow to automate some DevOps actions. I am able to retrieve all the related work items of a work item through the below API.

[https://dev.azure.com/{organizationname}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=600&$expand=all&api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganizationname%7D/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=600&$expand=all&api-version=6.0)

But I don't know how to close \ how to change the state of those work items automatically. I can't see any APIs. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

In the body update the `State` field:

```
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.State",
  "value": "Closed"
}
```

Comment: It works. Additional information.. The content-type should be 'application/json-patch+json'. Also, the request body must be enclosed by square brackets [].